# Swift Firebase - is it possible to do 2 queries in each other?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My user selects a "Business Category" and "Business Type". This query beneath is to make sure I am pulling the matching businesses to the selected "Business Category" which is "self.businessCategory". Then, I need to do another query on the results of the query for "Business Category" to match with "Business Type" which is "self.businessType". How can this be achieved? As far as I know, I can do something like "hasChild" yet that doesn't actually check what type only that this business has a child named "type".

```
//snapshot.hasChild(self.businessType)

func getTableViewData() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "businessCategory").queryEqual(toValue: self.businessCategory).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

    }) 
}
```

Comment: I believe what you are asking is how to filter your results by Business Category and then once you have all of the businesses of a specific Category, then filter those results for Business Type. If so, you can't directly do that in Firebase, however, there are several techniques to make it happen. We would need to see your Firebase Structure though to really understand your use case. Please include that in your question as text, no images (so if we need to use it in an answer, we don't have to retype it). To get a snippet, use the Firebase Console->Export JSON.

Comment: Im just going to do a query by type since all types are different in each category.

Comment: If the question is no longer valid, delete it so others don't attempt to answer - it keeps the site uncluttered.